# get GET variables from container on iframe?

Tags: php, iframe

I need to check for variables passed in a GET from an iframe. Is this possible?

E.G how do I echo the variable `$_GET['postID']` in the iframe?

Comment: `echo $_GET['postID'];`, nothing is different.

Comment: if your parent is receiving the GET, just pass it through in your iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the get variables of the parent frame, from within the iframe? If you want to do that you'll either need to pass the variable on in the iframe src, or write the value to the session and then read the session from within the iframe (if it's on the same domain).

The child frame is a completely separate HTTP request, and can't read any of the non-persistent data from the parent, unless the parent explicitly passes them along, or writes them to a (semi-)persistent datastore.